# Generic vs General property of reducedness in a family of projective schemes

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, deformation-theory, hilbert-schemes

Let $\pi:\mathcal{X} \to B$ be a flat family of projective schemes, $B$ is irreducible. Let $\mathrm{Spec} K$ be a *generic* point on $B$. Denote by $\mathcal{X}_K$, the pull-back of $\mathcal{X}$. This is flat, projective on $K$. It will then follow that $\mathcal{X}_{K_{\mathrm{red}}}$, the associated reduced scheme, is also flat, projective scheme over $K$. Assume that there exists a subfamily of $\pi$, say $\pi':\mathcal{X}' \to B$, a flat family of projective schemes satisfying $\mathcal{X}'_b \subset \mathcal{X}_b$ for all $b \in B$ and $\mathcal{X}'_K = \mathcal{X}_{K_{\mathrm{red}}}$. Does this mean that for a *general* closed point $b \in B$, the fiber $\mathcal{X}'_b=\mathcal{X}_{b_{\mathrm{red}}}$, the associated reduced scheme? If not true in general, is there any known condition on $B$ or $\pi$ under which this could hold true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is true if you assume moreover that $(\mathcal{X}_K)_{red}$ is *geometrically* reduced -- in particular, in characteristic $0$. First of all, note that set-theoretically $\mathcal{X}'_b=\mathcal{X}_b$ for all $b$ in $B$ : since $\pi $  open,  $\pi (\mathcal{X}-\mathcal{X}')$ is an open subset of $B$ which does not contain the generic point, therefore it is empty. Now the subset $U\subset B$ of points $b$ such that $\mathcal{X}'_b$ is geometrically reduced is open in $B$ (EGA IV, Thm. 12.2.4), so for $b\in U\ $ $\mathcal{X}'_b$ is reduced, and therefore equal to $(\mathcal{X}_b)_{red}$.

I am not an expert in characteristic $p$ but I suspect there might be counter-examples if one does not assume that $(\mathcal{X}_K)_{red}$ is geometrically reduced.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am interested only in the characteristic $0$ case.

Comment: Here is a counterexample as abx suggests. Let $X$ be smooth connected of dimension $d>0$ over a perfect field $k$ of characteristic $p>0$ and let $\pi$ be the *relative* Frobenius morphism $X\rightarrow X^{(p)} =: B$ over $k$ (e.g., $t\mapsto t^p$ on the affine $t$-line over $k$). Let $X'=X$. The map $\pi$ is finite flat of degree $p^d$ with generic fiber that is *reduced* (corresponds to $K \hookrightarrow K^{1/p}$ since $k$ is perfect, as one sees by expressing a dense open in $X$ as etale over an affine space over $k$) but the fiber over every closed point of $B$ is non-reduced since $d>0$.

Comment: If one replaces "reduced" with "irreducible" but omits the "geometric" aspect then the same failure of spreading-out occurs in any characteristic; e.g., $t \mapsto t^n$ on the affine line over an algebraically closed field of char. not dividing $n$ (irreducible generic fiber but reducible fibers over all closed points).  So it is genuinely valuable to *understand* the proof of EGA IV$_3$, 12.2.4 so as to appreciate the origin of the "geometric fiber" requirement for spreading-out to work. This is not a matter of pathology-avoidance in char. $p$, but rather of the power of the Nullstellensatz.

Comment: @abx: This is most probably, a dumb question. Is it obvious that if every fiber of $\pi'$ is non-reduced then the generic fiber $\mathcal{X}'_K$ is non-reduced? In other words, why is the $U$ mentioned in your answer non-empty?

Comment: Because it contains the generic point by your hypothesis.